What is the alternative lib for KMP animated icons?
In my only android project I used this code to deal with animated icons:
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi::class)
fun rememberDrawable(@DrawableRes icon: Int, checked: Boolean? = null): Painter {
    return if (checked != null)
        rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(
            atEnd = checked,
            animatedImageVector = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(id = icon)
        )
    else
        painterResource(id = icon)
}

which is possible by this lib:

androidx-animation-graphics-android = { module = "androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics-android", version.ref = "animation-graphics-android" }

to deal with such xml icons:
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24"
            android:viewportHeight="24">
            <group android:name="group">
                <path
                    android:name="path_1"
                    android:fillColor="#000"
                    android:pathData="M 15.781 2.5 C 14.796 2.548 13.842 3.041 12.906 3.938 L 4.719 11.844 C 4.331 12.218 3.952 12.884 3.875 13.406 L 3.5 16.375 C 3.327 17.784 4.496 18.762 5.969 18.531 L 9.188 18.031 C 9.75 17.941 10.463 17.598 10.844 17.219 L 19.031 9.344 C 20.93 7.524 21.085 5.678 18.875 3.781 C 17.79 2.855 16.766 2.452 15.781 2.5 Z M 15.844 3.5 C 16.59 3.465 17.345 3.785 18.219 4.531 C 19.939 6.008 19.847 7.153 18.344 8.594 L 10.156 16.5 C 9.923 16.732 9.391 16.973 9.031 17.031 L 5.813 17.531 C 4.968 17.663 4.412 17.218 4.5 16.5 L 4.875 13.563 C 4.918 13.27 5.179 12.782 5.406 12.563 L 13.594 4.656 C 14.356 3.926 15.098 3.535 15.844 3.5 Z" />
                <path
                    android:name="path_2"
                    android:fillColor="#000"
                    android:pathData="M 11.813 5.125 C 11.54 5.172 11.36 5.447 11.406 5.719 C 11.876 8.452 14.28 10.507 17.281 10.781 C 17.556 10.806 17.819 10.619 17.844 10.344 C 17.869 10.069 17.65 9.806 17.375 9.781 C 14.81 9.547 12.765 7.802 12.375 5.531 C 12.328 5.259 12.085 5.078 11.813 5.125 Z" />
                <path
                    android:name="path_3"
                    android:fillColor="#000"
                    android:pathData="M 3 20.5 C 2.724 20.5 2.5 20.724 2.5 21 C 2.5 21.276 2.724 21.5 3 21.5 L 21 21.5 C 21.276 21.5 21.5 21.276 21.5 21 C 21.5 20.724 21.276 20.5 21 20.5 L 3 20.5 Z" />
            </group>
            <group android:name="group_1">
                <path
                    android:name="path"
                    android:fillColor="#000000"
                    android:pathData="M 8.625 14.875 C 8.349 14.875 8.125 15.099 8.125 15.375 L 8.125 21 C 8.125 21.276 8.349 21.5 8.625 21.5 C 8.901 21.5 9.125 21.276 9.125 21 L 9.125 15.875 L 14.875 15.875 L 14.875 21 C 14.875 21.276 15.099 21.5 15.375 21.5 C 15.651 21.5 15.875 21.276 15.875 21 L 15.875 15.375 C 15.875 15.099 15.651 14.875 15.375 14.875 L 8.625 14.875 Z M 5.25 2.5 C 3.731 2.5 2.5 3.731 2.5 5.25 L 2.5 18.75 C 2.5 20.269 3.731 21.5 5.25 21.5 L 18.75 21.5 C 20.269 21.5 21.5 20.269 21.5 18.75 L 21.5 9.563 C 21.5 8.833 21.203 8.141 20.688 7.625 L 16.375 3.313 C 15.859 2.797 15.167 2.5 14.438 2.5 L 5.25 2.5 Z M 5.25 3.5 L 14.438 3.5 C 14.902 3.5 15.359 3.672 15.688 4 L 20 8.313 C 20.328 8.641 20.5 9.098 20.5 9.563 L 20.5 18.75 C 20.5 19.716 19.716 20.5 18.75 20.5 L 5.25 20.5 C 4.283 20.5 3.5 19.716 3.5 18.75 L 3.5 5.25 C 3.5 4.284 4.284 3.5 5.25 3.5 Z" />
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="group">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="scaleX"
                    android:valueFrom="1"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="scaleY"
                    android:valueFrom="1"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="pivotY"
                    android:valueFrom="12"
                    android:valueTo="12"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="pivotX"
                    android:valueFrom="12"
                    android:valueTo="12"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="group_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="scaleY"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="1"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="scaleX"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="1"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="pivotY"
                    android:valueFrom="12"
                    android:valueTo="12"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
                    android:propertyName="pivotX"
                    android:valueFrom="12"
                    android:valueTo="12"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>

But that doesn't work in KMP:
:composeApp:desktopMain: Could not resolve androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics-android:1.7.5.
Required by:
    project :composeApp

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

What is the possible way to get the same result in KMP?
